# Like and equal SQL order by equal?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Say I have the following table:

```
ID      Author
---------------------
1       Bill
2       Joe
3       Bill and Joe
4       Bill
```

And I want a result set that would come from:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE Author LIKE '%Bill%' OR Author = 'Bill'
```

How could I order it so that the rows matched with equality are the first rows returned and the like matches comes after? e.g. The query would return `1,4,3`.  I am using MySQL but would take answers in any DB.

Comment: You should consider normalizing the table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT  id
FROM    YourTable
WHERE  Author LIKE '%Bill%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Author = 'Bill' THEN 0
              ELSE 1
         END
```

You can probably just do `ORDER BY Author != 'Bill'` as well - Not sure about ordering by boolean expressions in MySQL.

Comment: @nick - Any idea about my after thought `ORDER BY Author != 'Bill'` will that effectively get treated as `0` and `1` as I assume might happen?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
WHERE Author LIKE '%Bill%'
order by if(author='Bill',1,2)
```

Comment: You're right Martin. I was just thinking about sorting. edited post.

Answer (score 0):

If that test needs to be expanded to several variables, I have expanded a bit Martin's answer in the following manner (for instance on 3 criteria):

```
SELECT  id
FROM    YourTable
WHERE  Author LIKE '%Bill%' 
ORDER BY 
(CASE WHEN criteria_1='target_1' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) 
*
(CASE WHEN criteria_2='target_2' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) 
*
(CASE WHEN criteria_3='target_3' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Best regards (and many thanks to Martin),

Answer (score -1):

I have tested your data in db and ORDER BY works as you wish without any problems but you can use the following query:

New query:

```
select Author, CONCAT(Author, ' ') as text_n 
from table where Author like '%Bill%' order by text_n;
```

Your edited query:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE Author LIKE '%Bill%' order by Author;
```